# How do I add a field that is based on another in a query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am making a query to search tables with the following properties:

- Order #
- Customer # -> based on Order #
- Organization -> based on Customer #

The query that I'm working with already has the first 2, ordered by Order # from a table that also contains Customer #. The organization field that I'd like to use is in a separate table that is ordered by the Customer # (which is the same as in the other table). Is there a way that I can add the organization field into the query so that it reflects the correct organization for the customer?

Comment: You'll need to show us some SQL code and/or the structure & relationship of your tables - it is very difficult to advise based on the information currently provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is how to join two tables.

Assuming the following tables:

- `Table1` containing the fields `OrderNr` and `CustomerNr`
- `Table2` containing the fields `CustomerNr` and `OrganizationNr`

The query would be:

```sql
Select Table1.OrderNr, Table1.CustomerNr, Table2.OrganizationNr
From Table1 Inner Join Table2 On Table1.CustomerNr = Table2.CustomerNr
```